# How to hide email signup forms after a user joins the email list?

Tags: forms, email, aweber

I use Aweber to host multiple email sign up forms on my blog.

How can I hide these forms once someone joins the email list? There is no need to ask them to sign up once they have already joined and it would make the site cleaner and more user friendly.

Can you link the users IP address to the Aweber list, verify that they have signed up, and then remove the forms? Or somehow drop a cookie to do the same thing?

I've never done anything like this, so I'm just trying to get a feel for the options and what it would take.

Answer (score 0):

As the IP-Adress changes, it would be better to set a cookie for a long time. If this cookie is set you can hide the form.